# What is the idiomatic way to obtain a sequence of columns from an incanter dataset?

Tags: clojure, incanter

What's the best way to get a sequence of columns (as vectors or whatever) from an Incanter data set?

I thought of:

```
(to-vect (trans (to-matrix my-dataset)))
```

But Ideally, I'd like a lazy sequence.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `$` macro.

```
=> (def data (to-dataset [{:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 4}]))
=> ($ :a data)  ;; :a column
=> ($ 0 :all data) ;; first row

=> (type ($ :a data))
clojure.lang.LazySeq
```

Comment: True, type of ($ :a data) is LazySeq, but when asking for more than one column, e. g. ($ :all data) it is Dataset.  Is there any way of getting a sequence of columns when more than one is asked for?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code for [`to-vect`](https://github.com/liebke/incanter/blob/master/modules/incanter-core/src/incanter/core.clj#L1029) it makes use of `map` to build up the result, which is already providing one degree of lazyness. Unfortunately, it looks like the whole data set is first converted `toArray`, probably just giving away all the benefits of `map` lazyness.

If you want more, you probably have to dive into the gory details of the [Java object](http://jwork.org/jhepwork/api_extra/cern/colt/matrix/tdouble/impl/DenseColumnDoubleMatrix2D.html) effectively holding the matrix version of the data set and write your own version of to-vect.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the internal structure of the dataset.

```
user=> (use 'incanter.core)
nil
user=> (def d (to-dataset [{:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 4}]))
#'user/d
user=> (:column-names d)
[:a :b]
user=> (:rows d)
[{:a 1, :b 2} {:a 3, :b 4}]
user=> (defn columns-of
         [dataset]
         (for [column (:column-names dataset)]
           (map #(get % column) (:rows dataset))))
#'user/columns-of
user=> (columns-of d)
((1 3) (2 4))
```

Although I'm not sure in how far the internal structure is public API. You should probably check that with the incanter guys.